# Get NTFS permission for multiple paths using Get-ACL

Tags: powershell

I have designed a powershell script to get NTFS permissions for folders and sub folders from multiple paths defined in text file (each path entry is in new line). servers list is in text file by name servers.txt.
Script is working fine and permission output is wrote to csv file.
I need to capture exception in same output csv file in case there is any folder not having valid permission or path do not exists.
Please let me know how the exception in code can be added using try catch

Below is my code:

```
$FolderPath = Get-Content .\App-Path.txt
$FolderContent = Get-ChildItem $FolderPath -Recurse -Force -Directory
$Servers = Get-Content .\Servers.txt
$Output = @() 

ForEach ($Server in $Servers)
{
Write-Host "Getting NTFS permission from " $Server
ForEach ($Folder in ($FolderContent)) { 
    #$Acl = Get-Acl -Path $Folder.FullName
    $ACL = (Get-Acl $Folder.FullName).Access
    Write-Host "Getting permission for folder: " $Folder.FullName
    ForEach ($Access in $Acl) { 
$Properties = [ordered]@{'Server'=$Server;'Folder Name'=$Folder.FullName;'Group/User'=$Access.IdentityReference;'Permissions'=$Access.FileSystemRights;'Inherited'=$Access.IsInherited} 
$Output += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties 
    } 
}
}
$Output | export-csv -path .\NTFSPerm.csv

$CSV = Import-Csv ".\NTFSPerm.csv"
$No_Numeric = ForEach($Line in $CSV)
                {
                    If($Line.Permissions -notlike '-1610612736' -and $Line.Permissions -notlike '268435456')
                    {$Line}

                } $No_Numeric |Export-Csv ".\NTFS-Permission.CSV" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Use `Try...Catch` to trap the error and add a property in your output object to contain either an error (if there is one) or a dummy value like "OK"

Comment: I am not sure how to use Try catch. Could you please suggest on it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the point of your `$Servers` since it's only being used for display purposes?

Comment: Code line $Servers = Get-Content .\Servers.txt having a variable $Servers which is holding number of servers listed in Servers.txt. this is being used for running script on multiple servers from single location.